# Set the fill color (not the stroke color) for the QPainter in QT

Tags: c++, qt, colors, qt5, qpainter

How could I set the fill color (not the stroke color) for the `QPainter` in QT?

For example, I have a code which is responsible for filling the rectangle. It looks like:

```
painter.fillRect(fillRect, Qt::SolidPattern);
```

Where the type of `painter` is `QPainter`. Of course, I know that it is possible to specify the color in the case as a second parameter, but I have such a design in my program that it would be a lot better if I could set the `painter` fill color beforehand (by default the color is black).

I tried to use `painter.setBackground(Qt::yellow);`, but it did not help.

Hm. According to [this](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setBrush) we have:

> Sets the painter's brush to the given brush.
>
> The painter's brush defines how shapes are filled.

So, I would expect something like

```
QRect fillRect;
painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
painter.fillRect(fillRect, Qt::SolidPattern);
```

to work. But it does not. What am I doing wrong?

After debugging it turns out that the `setBrush` method does not update the brush color at all:
[image]

The color `rgb` stays the same: (0, 0, 0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fillRect()` accepts a `QBrush` as a second parameter, so I could use it:

```
painter.fillRect(r, QBrush(Qt::yellow, Qt::SolidPattern));
```

---

Update:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(128, 128);
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    QRect r= pixmap.rect();
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
    painter.fillRect(r, painter.brush());
    painter.end();

    QLabel w;
    w.setPixmap(pixmap);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173304/discussion-on-answer-by-eyllanesc-set-the-fill-color-not-the-stroke-color-for).

Comment: @BhargavRao Okay I understand, but it would not be better to propose it as a change, so we would save you work :)

Comment: Yup, it's already proposed here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room